# The code is not working on some points. problem in ajax and php code

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want someone to help me in my ajax code. The problem is (1) when i am trying to add if(isset) on action it is not inserting data into database without this it works fine, work with if(isset) that's my need. (2)
when data has inserted the success popup is not working.

**index.php**

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AJAX PRACISE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FOR INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submit').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({

            url: "action.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            success: function(){
                 swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
            }

          });

        });

      });
    </script>
    <!-- FOR INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE -->

  </head>
  <body>

        <form action="action.php" id="myform" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="exampleInputPassword1">
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="insbtn" value="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

***action.php***

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($con, "ajax");

if (isset($_POST['insbtn'])) {
  $email= $_POST['email'];
  $password= $_POST['password'];

  $sql ="INSERT INTO `user` (`ID`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$email', '$password')";

  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}

 ?>
```

I know the two problems are too basic but I am new in ajax that is the reason that I am stuck. Thanks... :)

Comment: in `isset()` check `email` and `password` and not `insbtn`

Comment: change button to input tag 

Your script is open to SQL Injection Attack.  You should consider using prepared parameterized statements in either the MYSQLI_ or PDO API's instead of concatenated values

Answer (score 1):

Here with `$('#myform').serialize()` , submit button is not included, so you have to check in backend as `if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))`

Also after insert, echo something and compare in ajax response.

**Note**: *your code is open to SQL Injection, so protect it*.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submit').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          
          console.log($('#myform').serialize());
          
          $.ajax({

            url: "action.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            success: function(resp){
                if(resp == 'success'){
                  swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
                } else {
                  alert('cant insert data');
                }
                 
            }

          });

        });

      });
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AJAX PRACISE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FOR INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE -->
 
 </head>
  <body>

        <form action="action.php" id="myform" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="exampleInputPassword1">
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="insbtn" value="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Your **action.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($con, "ajax");

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $email= $_POST['email'];
  $password= $_POST['password'];

  $sql ="INSERT INTO `user` (`ID`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$email', '$password')";

  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 // after insert echo something
 echo "success";
}

 ?>
```

Comment: If you want to check if the button is clicked or not then you can add a hidden text input field to the form and give it a name, then just assign a value on click of the submit button of the form before calling the ajax function. That will include the hidden field's value inside the form.serialize() and will be able to get the value to check in action.php page.
For protecting your sql code from sql injection attack you can read this article - [Mysql sql injection prevention](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection).